# Unexpected NA in guide_coloursteps

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm surprised by the inclusion of `NA` values in the guide when using `guide_coloursteps` in the following example, since there are no `NA` values in the data.

```r
library(ggplot2)

df <- tidyr::drop_na(palmerpenguins::penguins)

ggplot(df, aes(x = species, y = island, fill = bill_length_mm)) +
  geom_tile() +
  scale_fill_distiller(
    guide = guide_coloursteps()
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-09-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Note that this works as expected (i.e. no `NA`s in the guide) if we use `scale_fill_binned` instead, but this makes it harder to combine with the brewer palettes and various other `scale_fill_*` functions from external packages.

Can someone explain if this is intended behaviour, and if so how the `NA` values may be removed from the guide?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue. I am using `R v 4.0.02`,` tidyr v 1.1.1` and `ggplot2 v 3.3.2`. I get a plot with no NA values in the scale: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJwbg.png.

Comment: Upgrading `ggplot2` from `3.3.0` to `3.3.2` did the trick. Guess there must've been a bug somewhere between then. Thanks!